# How to import a Jar into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I have been making something in eclipse until just recently I had some technical issues causing my hard drive to be completely destroyed and I lost everything except a jar file.

I wish to start working on it again but am not sure what to do since I have no source file just the jar. I tried decompiling and importing except it made a mess of my code and will take forever to clean it up. Hopefully I did something wrong and there is a much easier way to do this.

Comment: So your issue is decompiling a .class file into readable source code?

Comment: If all you have is a compiled jar, then find some decompilation tools to extract it in a form that is workable. There are loads of tools around

Comment: @Petesh Yes, but the code quality will never reach the original code, especially when it comes to variable names and comments.

Comment: Do you need to change the logic of your jar or just use its classes in the new project?

Comment: @Sebastian well duh. jeez, decompilation tools aren't magical. I was suggesting trying different tools that may make reconstruction better. There is no magical pill (sarcasm not intended)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the sources of the JAR you can make a dependency to it within eclipse (right click on project -> Build Path -> Dependencies). 
Or if you use a build tool (maven, gradle, etc.) put the jar to your local/remote repository and put it as dependency to your build file.

Otherwise decompile the JAR for e.g. with [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) and put the java files to your eclipse project.